Проблема с установкой коннектора MariaDB для Python
Пытаюсь установить коннектор MariaDB для Python следующим образом:
pip install mariadb ...и получаю такую ошибку:

Could not find InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C. Please make sure MariaDB Connector/C is installed or specify the InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C by setting the environment variable MARIADB_CC_INSTALL_DIR.

Отсюда ( https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/c-connector ) качаю коннектор для C и устанавливаю его. Но ничего не происходит, при попытке установки MariaDB получаю все ту же ошибку. ОС Windows 11. Версия pip 24.2.
В чем дело?
UPD:
Добавляю часть логов сборки
mariadb_cursor.c
      mariadb/mariadb_cursor.c(1107): error C2039: "db_execute_generate_request" ist kein Member von "st_mariadb_methods".
      C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include\mysql.h(852): note: Siehe Deklaration von "st_mariadb_methods"
      mariadb/mariadb_cursor.c(1227): error C2039: "db_execute_generate_request" ist kein Member von "st_mariadb_methods".
      C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include\mysql.h(852): note: Siehe Deklaration von "st_mariadb_methods"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2


"качаю коннектор для C и устанавливаю его" - ¿Вас не смутило, что там нет варианта для Windows 11?

@user7860670, Для версии 3.3.11-GA есть соответствующая, называется MS Windows (64-bit x86)

¿А переменную окружения MARIADB_CC_INSTALL_DIR после установки выставили в командном интерпретаторе, где питон запускаете?

@user7860670, да! Но получаю следующую ошибку: ERROR: Failed building wheel for mariadb и ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (mariadb)

Ну тогда стоит прочитать лог сборки и выяснить, что там случилось.

@user7860670, добавил!

Видимо версия Connector не соответствует той, которую ожидает расширение.

Проще взять pymysql и не мучаться, если нет каких-то особых причин использовать именно connector

@andreymal, да, но раньше все одной командой ставилось, pip install mariadb, а когда я снес и заново поставил Python получилась такая вот фигня...

Значит внутренний телепат подсказыает мне, что раньше у вас был питон 3.12, а теперь 3.13, под который сборку mariadb ещё не сделали

@andreymal, да python --version выдает 3.13.0...т.е. получается, вы решили мою проблему? Благодарочка!
